# Swap bits (or just access them) in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm going to come out with a disclaimer and say this is my homework problem. So I don't necessarily want you to solve it, I just want some clarification.

The exact problem is this:

> Write a function to swap odd and even bits in an integer with as few
>   instructions as possible (e.g., bit 0 and bit 1 are swapped, bit 2 and
>   bit 3 are swapped, and so on).

It also hints that no conditional statements are required.

I kind of looked into it and I discovered if I somehow separate the even and odd bits I can use shifts to accomplish this. What I don't understand is how to manipulate individual bits. In python (programming language I'm used to) it's easy with the index operator as you can just do number[0] for example and you can get the first bit. How do you do something like this for assembly?

EDIT:
So @jotik, thanks for your help. I implemented something like this:

```
mov edi, ebx
and edi, 0x5555555555555555
shl edi, 1
mov esi, ebx
and esi, 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
shr esi, 1
or edi, esi
mov eax, edi
```

And when I saw the | operator, I was thinking OR was ||. Silly mistake.

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C. Conversion to asm is trivial.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **question and answer** site, so remove your solution from the *question* and post it as a proper *answer*.

Comment: which 32-bit register can store such number as `0x5555555555555555`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In assembly one can use [bit masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) together with other [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) to archive your result.

```
result = ((odd-bit-mask & input) << 1) | ((even-bit-mask & input) >> 1)
```

where `odd-bit-mask` is a value with all odd bits set (`1`) and even bits unset (`0`); and `even-bit-mask` is a value with all even bits set (`1`) and odd bits unset. For 64-bit values, the odd and even bit masks would be (in hexadecimal notation) `0x0x5555555555555555` and `0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` respectively.

So the pseudocode of your assembly algorithm would probably look similar to the following:

```
oddbits  = input & 0x5555555555555555
oddbits  = oddbits << 1
evenbits = input & 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
evenbits = evenbits >> 1
result   = oddbits | evenbits
```

where `&` is a bitwise AND operation, `|` is a bitwise OR operation, `<<` and `>>` are the bitwise shift left and bitwise shift right operations respectively.

PS: You can find some other useful bit manipulation tricks on Sean Eron Anderson's [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) webpage.

Comment: Ok I saw something like this, but what exactly is that? And how do I implement it in assembly? And as a side note, does the | operator just magically put the even and odd bits in the right order?

Comment: @user1157549 you are asking very basic questions about programming. This can be found in introductory books and is most likely taught in very first classes in your school. Certainly those are not magic operators, but bit-shift and bitwise logical operators. In order to understand them you might want to perform some more research on the internet and to try to solve few exercises on paper. Those operators are very natural for silicon computers and have direct analogs in virtually any assembly.

Comment: And before the bitwise shift, evenbits is the same as input xor oddbits which is a smaller instruction. Anyway, I think you can reduce this to at most 6 instructions using only ebx and eax, given that ebx doesn't have to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints:

- Bitwise boolean operations (these usually have 1:1 counterparts in assembly, but if everything else fails, you can construct them by cleverly combining several XOR calls)

  - bitwise AND: 0b10110101 & 0b00011000 → 0b00010000
  - bitwise  OR: 0b10110101 & 0b00011000 → 0b10111101
  - bitwise XOR: 0b10110101 & 0b00011000 → 0b10101101
- Bit shifts

  - shift x by n bits to the left (x << n): 0b00100001 << 3 → 0b00001000
  - shift x by n bits to the right (x >> n): 0b00100001 >> 3 → 0b00000100

There's also rotating bit shift, where bits "shifted out" appear on the other side, but this is not as widely supported in hardware.